# Help with integrating new title elements into my provided template

Tags: titles

Total newbee here.

At the moment I am writing the final paper of my apprenticeship. I have a template from my company, this already provides plenty of classes. However, my title page needs to have my candidate number on it. How can i add a new title element to a document using class `bfhthesis`?

This is my document:

```
% define document class
\documentclass[
    report,               % paper format
    12pt,               % fontsize
    bibliography=totoc,   % If enabled add bibliography to TOC
    listof=totoc,         % If enabled add lists to TOC
    bilingual,
%   monolingual,
    BCOR=1mm,
    titleimage-ratio=34,
    ngerman,
]{bfhthesis}              % BFH Thesis Class

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    
    \title{title}
    \subtitle{subtitle}
    \author{surname name}
    \institution{institution}
    \department{department}
    \version{1.2}
    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\width]{img/titleimg.png}}
    \expert{surname name, surname name}
    
    %----------------  BFH tile page   -----------------------------------------
    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    
    
    %------------ TABLEOFCONTENTS ----------------
    \tableofcontents
    
    %------------ START MAIN PART ----------------
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{Abstract}
        lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  `bfhthesis` is not a standard class, so we won't be able to do much.  But if the class isn't what you need, why not use a standard class?  You can also try `\author{lersle\\cand no 1234}`.

Comment: what do you mean by  "Here are the predefined classes:" ? a latex document only has one document class, specified by `\documentclass{...}` so in your case the document class is `bfhthesis` a non standard class that you have not shown.

Comment: @Teepeemm `\author{lersle\\cand no 1234}` didn't work, how would you solve this if it would be an standard class?

Comment: If nothing else, I would remove the `\maketitle` and make my own title page.  With a standard class, you could probably adjust `\maketitle` to include the information you want (or possibly `\maketitle\\\textbf{cand no 1234}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry, my bad. i meant "predefined Cl variables". how would i able to pull the source of `bfhthesis`? This is the url i got the example from: [link](https://latex.ti.bfh.ch/_downloads/2895663a5b1acd6903a7e8c85450a414/bfh-ci_2.1.5.zip)

Comment: We're probably not going to download and unzip a random internet file.  If you have `bfhthesis`, then somewhere you have `bfhthesis.cls`.  If it's not in your local directory, then type `kpsewhich bfhthesis.cls` on a command line.

Comment: @Teepeemm good point, i think it's not worth to invest hours into this problem, i will use a standard class and remodel the look of `bfhthesis`.
Thanks anyway and sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: The class file is available on CTAN [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bfh-ci/tex/bfhthesis.cls), part of the [bfh-ci](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bfh-ci) bundle

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is unclear, where and how the candidate number should be printed. Here one example with number but without a title for that number:

```
\documentclass[
    report,               % paper format
    12pt,               % fontsize
    bibliography=totoc,   % If enabled add bibliography to TOC
    listof=totoc,         % If enabled add lists to TOC
    bilingual,
%   monolingual,
    BCOR=1mm,
    titleimage-ratio=34,
    ngerman,
]{bfhthesis}              % BFH Thesis class
\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    
    \title{title}
    \subtitle{subtitle}
    \author{surname name\newline candidate number}
    \institution{institution}
    \department{department}
    \version{1.2}
%    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\width]{img/titleimg.png}}
    \expert{surname name, surname name}
    
    %----------------  BFH tile page   -----------------------------------------
    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    
    
    %------------ TABLEOFCONTENTS ----------------
    \tableofcontents
    
    %------------ START MAIN PART ----------------
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{Abstract}
        lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: candidate number below author name]

If you also want a title  for it, you IMHO would have to change the definition of `\versioninformation`. The original definition could be found in `bfhlayout.sty`. However, if you have been instructed to use this class or template and are then required to deviate from it, the supervisor should also be able to tell you how to do this.